# Database Reindex

Tags: sql-server

I would know what the reindex query does to the DB

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"
GO
EXEC sp_updatestats
GO
```

I saw that after running this statement, db performances are quite better, but I don't really know which fields are affected.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: both 2008 R2 and 2012

Comment: Why dont you search a bit about [DBCC DBREINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181671.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice script (probably you got it from Pinal Dave's website?) that performs a reindex over all your tables. So it can involve all your indexes on all your tables. 
The third parameter 80 indicates the fill factor of the index. The indexes you have rebuilt contain 20% of free space.

DBCC DBREINDEX is deprecated and should be avoided to guarantee compatibility with future versions of SQL Server. USE ALTER INDEX instead.

SQL Server does not keep history of which indexes are affected, but this query might help:

```
SELECT      name AS StatName
            , STATS_DATE(object_id, stats_id) AS LastStatsUpdate
FROM        sys.stats
WHERE       LEFT(name, 4) != '_WA_';
```

Comment: thanks for the comment Peter, but I would know what happens to each table. Does the script write in every _id field on each table? I'm not sure I have correctly understood

Comment: @tizionario: it does not do any updates in your tables. Just in your indexes.
Indexes just point to the rows in your table. So if your index changes, only that pointer is changed. No data in your table changes when you perform an reindex. A nice article about indexes can be found here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy.